# How configure ng-packagr to build library without optimizations

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have library which builds with ng-packagr. I need to debug some code in this library, but within another project. How can I configure my library build script without any optimizations (like unnamed chunks and minimized code)?